# Using regex to get string between two different characters

Tags: regex

I'm struggling to find the right syntax for the following string:

```
^Lorem/ipsum dolor sit/amet consectetur adipiscing/elit
```

Here, I want to extract the word between `^` and `/` *and* the first word after the first `/`. That is: `Lorem` and `ipsum`.

Moreover, how do I change the syntax if I want to extract the word after the second `/`? This would be `amet`.

Comment: You might get much better answers if the question were posted as it should be, with efforts from your side, and a regex flavor specified.

Comment: Please tag your question with the programming/scripting language or tool you're using. It also helps if you specify more examples, especially if there are any exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts:

1. First you want to match everything after a `^` and before a `/`:

   `/\^([^\/]*)/`

   - `\^` matches the character `^` literally
   - 1st Capturing group `([^\/]*)`

     - `[^\/]` match a single character not present in the list below
     - Quantifier: `*` Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
   - `\/` matches the character / literally
2. Second you want to match every word after a `/`:

   `/\/([^\s\/]*)/g`

   - `\/` matches the character `/` literally
   - 1st Capturing group `([^\s\/]*)`

     - `[^\s\/]` match a single character not present in the list below
     - Quantifier: `*` Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
     - `\s` match any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]`
     - `\/` matches the character `/` literally
   - `g` modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)

**Code** (PHP):

```
$str = "^Lorem/ipsum dolor sit/amet consectetur adipiscing/elit"; 

// Part one:
preg_match("/\\^([^\\/]*)/", $str, $matches);

$matches[1] == 'Lorem'; // True    

// Part two:
preg_match_all("/\\/([^\\s\\/]*)/", $str, $matches); 

$matches[1] == 'ipsum';
$matches[2] == 'amet';
$matches[3] == 'elit';
```

Code and explaination from wonderful tool [regex101](https://regex101.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The 2 words are in capture group 1 and 2. [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pY3eE8/1).

```
\^(\w+)\/(\w+)
```

If you want to capture `amet`, use this:

```
\^(\w+)\/.+?\/(\w+)
```